# CompositionBatch: AddPart vs AddExport

Tags: .net, mef

What is the difference between the AddPart() and AddExport() in the composition batch class? When would I use one over the other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was wondering about the same thing and unfortunately haven't been able to find any documentation that describes the difference between AddPart, AddExport, (and AddExportedValue) concisely. Here is what I have learned so far:

A *part* in MEF terminology, is a component that provides capabilities (aka *exports*) and specifies dependencies (aka *imports*).

So when you call `batch.AddPart(something)` then you are telling MEF that "something" is a component that may provide *exports* and depends on one or more *imports*. 
If you call `batch.AddExport(new Export("someExport", () => something))` then you are telling MEF that "something" is a component that just provides *exports* without requiring any *imports*, i.e. MEF will ignore any `[Import]` annotations that may be specified in the "something" class.

Internally AddExport actually calls AddPart, but prior to that it wraps the passed object in a "SingleExportComposablePart", i.e. a ComposablePart returning an empty `IEnumerable<ImportDefinition>` on a call to `ComposablePart.ImportDefinitions`.